# Mathematica Module Not Returning Value

Tags: module, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I am new to Mathematica, and using a Module to perform a procedure, then return a value. However, Mathematica seems to be evaluating and returning symbolic values instead of the numerical value I want.

Questions I have are: When don't you use semicolons? And when do you use Return[value] instead of just writing "value"?

```
DumpVar[x_] := Print[ToString[HoldForm[x]], ":", x];
SetAttributes[DumpVar, {Listable, HoldAll}]

width = 1;
interval = width/2;

panelCoeff = 2;
lightAngle = Pi/3;

(*Panel and light equations*)

panel[x_] = Abs[panelCoeff x];(*panelCoeff ((x)^2);*)

light[x_] = Tan[lightAngle]*x;

getAngleAttack[offset_] := 
  Module[{bounce1x, l1a, lightSlope, panelSlope},
   light[x_] = light'[x] (x - offset) + panel[interval];
   DumpVar[offset];

   lightSlope = N[light'[offset]];
   u1S = light'[offset];
   u1[x_] = (u1S (x - offset)) + panel[interval]; 

   bounce1x = 
    x /. N[NSolve[u1[x] == panel[x] && x < interval && x > -interval, 
       x]];

   u1r[x_] = panel'[bounce1x] (x - bounce1x) + panel[bounce1x];

   If[Length[bounce1x] > 0,
     bounce1x = bounce1x[[1]];,
     bounce1x = offset;
     ]

    If[bounce1x > -interval && bounce1x < interval,

     lightSlope = N[u1'[bounce1x]];

     If[x <= 0,
      panelSlope := N[panelCoeff],
      panelSlope := -N[panelCoeff]];

     DumpVar[lightSlope];
     DumpVar[panelSlope];
     l1a = 
      N[ArcTan[(lightSlope - 
           panelSlope)/(1 + (panelSlope lightSlope))]];

     DumpVar[l1a];

     l1a
      Return[l1a]
     ]

    Return[l1a];
   ];


myint = getAngleAttack[0];
(*myint = N[f[10]];*)
DumpVar[myint];

Plot[{panel[x], light[x]}, {x, -.6, .6}]

myint = getAngleAttack[.5];
DumpVar[myint];
```

My goal is to be able to graph and integrate this function.

Comment: I have to work through this, but be careful in how you name your variables. It's not obvious what you mean by `light[x_] = light'[x] (x - offset) + panel[interval]`

Comment: @yoda: There's a few other issues too. Further down in the module is a bunch of problems. I'll post an answer with some notes.

Comment: I've added some additional notes to further simplify/explain some points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the middle of your block you have:

```
If[Length[bounce1x] > 0,
  bounce1x = bounce1x[[1]];,
  bounce1x = offset;
  ]
```

The format of `If` is as follows: `If[Condition, ValueIfTrue, ValueIfFalse]`

So `If[True, 3, 2]` returns 3, and `If[False, 3, 2]` returns 2. Your semicolons here are unnecessary, but you do need one at the end of the if statement:

```
If[Length[bounce1x] > 0,
  bounce1x = bounce1x[[1]],
  bounce1x = offset
  ];
```

Otherwise, Mathematica will interpret that as multiplication of that statement times whatever the next one to show up will be. In this case, you're returning `null` from that `If` statement, and it's being multiplied by the return value of the next `If` statement that comes up.

For `Module` the syntax is: `Module[{localvars}, ReturnValue]`

Which means whatever is the last statement that shows up without a semicolon is the ReturnValue. So for example the following module:

```
Module[{y},
   y = x * x;
   If[x < 0, -y, +y]
]
```

will return -y when x < 0, and +y otherwise. The one exception this is when `Return` shows up. Just like in most languages, you can return early from a function by using `Return`:

```
Module[{y},
   y = x * x;
   If[x < 0, 
      Return[-y],
      Return[+y]];
 (* We never reach this point to return null *)
 ];
```

---

With respect to your `Module`, I think this may be what you're trying to accomplish:

```
getAngleAttack[offset_] := 
 Module[{bounce1x, l1a, lightSlope, panelSlope}, 
  light[x_] = light'[x] (x - offset) + panel[interval];
  DumpVar[offset];

  lightSlope = N[light'[offset]];
  u1S = light'[offset];
  u1[x_] = (u1S (x - offset)) + panel[interval];

  bounce1x = 
   x /. N[NSolve[u1[x] == panel[x] && x < interval && x > -interval, 
      x]];

  u1r[x_] = panel'[bounce1x] (x - bounce1x) + panel[bounce1x];

  If[Length[bounce1x] > 0,
   bounce1x = bounce1x[[1]],
   bounce1x = offset];

   If[bounce1x > -interval && bounce1x < interval,

   lightSlope = N[u1'[bounce1x]];

   If[x <= 0,
    panelSlope := N[panelCoeff],
    panelSlope := -N[panelCoeff]];

   DumpVar[lightSlope];
   DumpVar[panelSlope];

   l1a = N[
     ArcTan[(lightSlope - panelSlope)/(1 + (panelSlope lightSlope))]];

   DumpVar[l1a];
   Return[l1a]
  ];
  l1a]
```

---

Another thing you should watch out for is any variables you use inside of a `Module`. If you run the following piece of code, you'll get `4, -113/5, 32` as the output values:

```
d = 4 (* d was 4 *)
Module[{a, b, c},
   a = 3;
   b = 2;
   c = 5;
   d = 32; (* Uh oh! I just overwrite whatever d was *)
   a^2 + b / c - d]
d (* d is now 32 *)
```

To avoid this, define any variables you're using as local variables within the start of the `Module`: `Module[{a, b, c, d}, ...]`

Comment: Thanks! I was having trouble figuring out that syntax, especially coming from programming languages where semicolons are in EVERY line. :-)

Comment: The semicolons here are necessary if you want to do something but NOT return a value. The semantics of semicolons in Mathematica are to suppress the return value of a statement, and instead return `null`. So in a sense, you *do* need semicolons on almost every line.

Comment: @Geekgirl Perhaps now is a good time to tell that ';' is actually -just like everything else in Mathematica- a function. In this case the function `CompoundExpression`,with `a;b` being  equivalent to `CompoundExpression[a,b]` and `a;b;` equivalent to `CompoundExpression[a,b,Null]`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, beat me to it. I wrote a more lengthy answer that included that.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to add a couple of things to [Mike's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139867/mathematica-module-not-returning-value/8140136#8140136).

First, semi-colons are way of building [compound expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html), and as Mike pointed out, they suppress the output of the immediately preceding statement. But, they're most useful in allowing you to chain multiple expressions together where only a single expression is expected, like in the body of a `Module`, as you're doing.  However, they're useful for simpler things like this contrived example

```
a = 5;
b = (Print[a]; a - 3)
```

Note the parentheses; `;` has a lower precedence than `=`, so

```
b = Print[a]; a - 3
```

would set b to the return value of `Print` which is `Null`.

To incorporate what Sjoerd was saying in his comment, the expression

```
b = (Print[a]; a - 3)
```

is interpreted as

```
Set[b, CompoundExpression[ Print[a], a - 3] ]
```

while the second, incorrect, form is interpreted as

```
CompoundExpression[ Set[b, Print[a]], a - 3]
```

If you want to see what form an expression takes, use [`FullForm[Hold[ expression ]]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hold.html) which reveals the internal form of an expression.  You need to use [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hold.html) when you don't want anything to be executed prior to examining its form, as would be the case with `Set`.

Second, when using an `If` expression to [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html) a variable to different values, it can be pulled out of the `If` statement, as follows

```
 bounce1x = If[Length[bounce1x] > 0, bounce1x[[1]], offset];
```

Since `If` will return either `bounce1x[[1]]` or `offset`.  This can greatly simplify your expressions.  This also works with [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`), like for `panelSlope`

```
panelSlope := If[x <= 0, N[panelCoeff], -N[panelCoeff]];
```

However, I wouldn't use `SetDelayed` here as you don't need to recalculate `panelSlope` every time you use it.  Also, you can simplify that a little by using [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitStep.html),

```
panelSlope = (1 - 2 UnitStep[x]) N[panelCoeff];
```

or, even

```
panelSlope = If[x<=0, 1, -1] N[panelCoeff];
```

([`Sign`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sign.html) wouldn't be appropriate here, as it will return zero when its parameter is 0.)

Lastly, there's a bug in your code with regards to `l1a`. Your `Module` returns it, but if the `bounce1x > -interval && bounce1x < interval` condition is not met, the `If` statement where it is set is not entered.  So, it will return something of the form `l1a$###` where `###` are numbers.  Also, I'd get rid of the `Return[ l1a ]` in that `If` statement entirely, as it is not necessary, `l1a` is set within the `If` statement.

Comment: @Sjoerd, sorry, I'm not as familiar with the "o" before "e" rules as I am with the "i" before "e" rules. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a helpful and thorough answer! It's exactly the information I was lacking. :-)